# understanding jboss framework - URL

Tags: java, jboss

I am trying to figure out what the following url does. 
http://server/abc/testmodule/runtest.do?action=edit&id=123

I am new to jboss/jsp but I am very familiar with .net.
When I see this url, I expect to see the physical folder called "abc" and subfolder called "testmodule" and a physical file "runtest". am i wrong? what does runtest.do? is "runtest" class and "do" is a method within it?

Comment: Please differentiate between a container, a framework, and other concepts. This has nothing to do with JBoss IMO. IIRC, .do is Struts convention.

Answer (score 1):

It could be anything--URLs can map to arbitrary resources. It might be a Struts action, it might be a servlet, it might be a Spring controller, etc.

You'd need to check your `web.xml` file and/or any framework configuration files, or provide more information.

(Also, JBoss isn't a framework, it's a Java EE container :)

Answer (score 0):

The `/abc` entry is the name of the context in which the application is running.  If it's a web app, deployed in a WAR file, that would be the name of the WAR that's deployed (`abc.war`).

The `.do` extension suggests a Struts or JSF action mapping.

There are two parameters passed in the GET: `action`, with value `edit`, and `id`, with value `123`.  Looks like a REST-ful API to me.

Comment: The `/abc` isn't necessarily an app context. It *may* be, but there's no reason it *must* be. Doesn't seem particularly RESTful, but that's a URL pattern bias on my part :)

Comment: If it's a WAR file it could be.

Comment: Yep, that's why I said it *may* be :)